# Why won't my Windows XP laptop start up again?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have an ASUS Eee PC Windows XP laptop that I've had for about a year. I tried to download a program onto my laptop and the next morning I tried to turn it on and all that would pop up is the background and then it would shut down. What would be the problem?

Comment: The causes and solutions to a problem like this are numerous.  Any more details would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why on earch would you tag this `yahoo`?

Comment: What kind of program did you download/install??

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the problems can be numerous, but what I would try is first hitting F8 on boot (hit it a few times early so you don't miss it), and trying "Last Known Good".

If that does not work, try system restore from "Safe Mode Command Prompt Only" (again F8 on boot). http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304449